# error on review list page

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, magento-1, review

In my observer for `core_layout_block_create_after`

I am checking

```
public function addButtonBlock($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

        if (($block->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') && ($block->getNameInLayout() == 'product.info')) {
            }}
```

It's working fine on Product View page , while on review list page with the form its giving an error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getFullActionName() on
>   string in
>   /var/www/html/meemee/app/code/community/Tebet/SocialShare/Model/Observer.php
>   on line 15, referer: http://localhost/meemee/asd.html

I am able to get an echo for **review_product_list**  for `$block->getAction()->getFullActionName()`
but while using it in if condition it throws error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting problem here.

Basically the problem is that the `getAction` method declared in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` is definitely what you need to use here and your code is definitely right.

It is supposed to return a `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` that you can use to get the full action name.

However, the `Mage_Review_Block_Form` block entirely rewrites the `getAction` method with the following code:

```
public function getAction()
{
    $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
    return Mage::getUrl('review/product/post', array('id' => $productId, '_secure' => $this->_isSecure()));
}
```

That code returns a string so you cannot call the `getFullActionName` method on it, that's the problem.

I'm not sure why the Magento team did use the same name as such an important function of the parent block, sounds like a bug to me.

What you can do avoid that is:

Either use the following code instead:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()
```

Or if you want to do things for a specific block and not every block created, add a condition to test the block class:

```
if ($block instanceof The_Block_You_Want)
{
    if (($block->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') && ($block->getNameInLayout() == 'product.info'))
        {
              //
        }
}
```

Of course that won't work if the block you want to test is the `Mage_Review_Block_Form` ^^

On a side note, please note that the following block also rewrite the `getAction` method: `Mage_Customer_Block_Newsletter` (and it also returns a string)

Comment: Good find! And a textbook argument for strict return types :)

Comment: true. really looking forward for return types beeing implemented in a far future :x

Comment: Yeah can't wait :)